# Is there an incentive to delete variables / array values / other stored items?

Tags: solidity, gas

I am working on an application where my storage will grow and grow. I *could* delete data as I go, but I dont see any incentive to do so. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Specifically talking about arrays, enumerableSets, and mappings

Answer (score 0):

Deleting items with the `delete` keyword gives a gas refund, so there is a good incentive to do memory cleanup.

Relevant posts:

[Delete or clear a mapping](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3922/delete-or-clear-a-mapping)

[Delete an entry in a mapping](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44433/delete-an-entry-in-a-mapping)